# "The system cannot find the file specified" trying to create Minecraft Mod

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to create a mod for Minecraft 1.12.2, I have set up my modding space with forge mdk and java jdk. when I come to run it to check see if it set up correctly i get this error:

```
Error:Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\Hayde\.IdeaIC2018.2\system\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: The system cannot find the file specified -> there seems to be your problem. are you sure your setup/path is correct?

Comment: Looks like you either don't have a JDK installed, or whatever tool you're using is looking for a different version than the one you have. You'll need to go into its settings and fix the path.

Comment: maybe JAVA_HOME does not point to the actual path of the JDK ?

Comment: i'm using intellij idea, Forge MDK 1.12.2 and Java JDK 1.8.0_181 if this is any help

Comment: and i have set my java home up should i try deleting the jdk and re downloading it?